# Why does typecasting a single byte to string not work in go?

Tags: go

I am trying to convert a single byte value to a string in golang. When I do a typecast of a byte to string like `string(byte)` and print the value I get `"{"` in response. I read other answers that the correct way to convert a byte to string would be `strconv.Itoa(int(bytevalue))`. Why does the former not work and why is the latter approach correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `string(bytevalue)` is a conversion, not a typecast.
The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) this about conversions from numeric types to a string:

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer.

The expression `string(byte(123))` evaluates to the string `"{"` because  `{` is the the string containing the UTF-8 representation of the rune 123.

Use  the strconv package to get the decimal representation of the byte.  The expression `strconv.Itoa(int(byte(123)))` evaluates to the string `"123"`.